# Use setTarget: message of a cell to make the target File's Owner

Tags: cocoa

I have a custom NSActionCell subclass, and I want to use setTarget: message to set it's target to File's Owner. Is there a way to get a pointer to File's Owner, or to do something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's owner should be an instance of one of your own classes. Connect an outlet of the FO to the cell instance, and send the `setTarget:` message from the FO (probably in `awakeFromNib`).

I'm not clear on why you want to send a `setTarget:` message in code, though. Why not just set the cell's target in IB?